# How to switch the src attribute of the img element back into jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created a script that changes an image when you click a button. The problem is with clicking again, because the src attribute remains the same. I would like after clicking again the source of the photo to go back to the initial src. I tried to do it using toggle method, but with positive effect.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('.logo').attr('src', 'http://domena.com/logo-1.jpg');
    });
});
```

I tried to solve it that way, but I failed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('.logo').toggle(
                function() {
                    $(this).attr('src', 'http://domena.com/logo-1.jpg');
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).attr('src', 'http://domena.com/logo-2.jpg');
                }
            );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `URL` of new `image` in an attribute of `<img>`, then you can get the current `image` ie `src` and next image(`data-new`) and interchange their values, like so -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        let curr_img = $('.logo').attr('src'); // get current image
        let new_img = $('.logo').attr('data-new'); // get new image to be shown
        
        $('.logo').attr({'src': new_img, 'data-new': curr_img}); // interchange their values
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- give next values as an attribute ie data-new here-->
<img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/247/564/png-transparent-computer-icons-user-profile-user-avatar-blue-heroes-electric-blue.png" class="logo" data-new="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/21/21104.svg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
<br>

<button id="button">Toggle image</button>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: "couldn't load the image". Unfortunately, I'm getting an error.

Comment: It probably means that you're giving wrong URL or path of the image.

Comment: OK,. I made a mistake, but after I'm fixed, I still have the same picture.

Comment: Did you perform all the steps from the answer?

Comment: OK, it's working. Thank you very much for your help. By the way, you taught me something new!

Comment: Lol. Happy to help.